# warning when trying to fill mapView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm trying to built an android application that shows the location in a map view. This is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.overblog.R;

public class EditMapSectionActivity extends MapActivity{

    private MapView _mapView;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.edit_section_map_activity);

        _mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fragment_background_color" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/scroll_view_padding_left"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/scroll_view_padding_right"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/scroll_view_padding_top" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/search_for_location" />

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/section_padding_top"
            android:apiKey="0t8UnajIfX1hZH27u-DCH40YuglmW1-1U51_wQA"
            android:background="@drawable/default_image_background"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/check_box"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:text="@string/section_cover_picture" >
        </CheckedTextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I am sure of my debug apiKey because i used it in other applications, i also sure that i added internet permission to my manifest.xml

When i run my app my mapView doesn't load the map.

I checked my logcat, i got this warning:

```
10-04 17:33:10.511: W/MapActivity(21034): Recycling dispatcher android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@40c5edd0
```

Do anyone know what this warning mean?

Comment: could you add your edit_section_map_activity.xml layout to your question?

Comment: i added it under the code, but i don't thing that's the problem!!

Comment: You said you added the internet permission but did your add `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>` in your manifest under `<application>`?

Comment: you said you are trying to get image from fragment, where is the fragment? Also what api level we targeting here?

Comment: sorry that's a wrong title , it is the title of an old question
thanks mentionning it

Comment: Have you tried removing the `android:background="@drawable/default_image_background"` declaration from `<com.google.android.maps.MapView >`, this may be your issue.

Comment: yes i tryed that, still have an empty map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to remove everything extra you have, verify that it is working at it's simplest state and then if you need the background, margin, etc declarations in your xml then insert them in one at a time and run your application. This will allow you to narrow down the blank maps and warning message culprit.

Assuming you have a valid API key I know the following code works:

**The xml side:**

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="InsertYourAPIKeyHERE"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:state_enabled="true" />
```

**The java side:**

```
public class EditMapSectionActivity extends MapActivity {

    private MapView _mapView;

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_section_map_activity);

        _mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);

    }
}
```

**The manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package=""
    android:versionCode=""
    android:versionName="" >

    <!-- Network Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".EditMapSectionActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i did as you sad, i created a sample project containing one activity and one layout. It worked
I used my apikey!!!

Comment: i will try to reput that on my project

Comment: Great, let me know how it turns out. FYI, if the margin is the issue then you can wrap the `com.google.android.maps.MapView` in another view (RelativeLayout, for example) with a fill_parent width and height and then set the margin attributes to that view, I can show an example if you need it.